# Visual Studio Installer Project and Network Drives

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, windows-installer

I have created an installer in Visual Studios 2010 and i added some custom actions. It is meant to be a workstation installer so it would check to see if certain files exist in the destination folder and move shortcuts around after. However if i use a UNC path or a mapped network drive path as the destination folder and use the commands `My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists` and `System.IO.File.Exists` they return false on a network drive. Is there a way to figure out in a custom action if the file exists. Currently I am using Windows XP to run the installer so UAC is not a factor here.

Answer (score 0):

Custom actions in a VS setup project run with the system account, which has no network privileges and so can't get to see them. Also, mapped drives are a user-profile thing, not system-wide, so they belong to a particular user, so the system account won't see them because of that too.

So there isn't a good way to do this. It might work if the custom action ran with the installing user's account, but then it would not be elevated, and you'd need to go into the CustomAction table in the MSI file and turn off the the msidbCustomActionTypeNoImpersonate bit.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368069(v=vs.85).aspx